# Problem firing method after AVAudioPlayer is finished playing

Tags: iphone, xcode, while-loop, avaudioplayer

I saw some similar questions with  different solutions, but I want to know if there's a way using something similar to what I've already come up with.

Essentially, a uiview will take one color when the player starts playing, and go back to the starting color when it is finished playing

```
- (void)playSoundWithColor {

self.image = self.pressedImage;

[audioPlayer play];

while ([audioPlayer isPlaying]) {


  if (audioPlayer.currentTime == audioPlayer.duration)
  self.image = self.startingImage;

}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do what you're trying to do is to make your class an AVAudioPlayerDelegate and to use

```
audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:successfully:
```

That method is called right when the player finishes and doesn't have any continuous loop and memory issues. It will give you the most reliable and efficient performance overall.